# RouteConfig function not found in angular2 rc4 issue (plain JS)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router, angular2-router3

After upgrading to RC4 I have this issue configuring router:

> ng.router.RouteConfig is not a function

I am using plain JavaScript.

This is how I bootstrap:

```
ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent,[
        ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        new ng.core.provide(ng.core.PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true}),
        new ng.core.provide(ng.common.LocationStrategy, {useClass: ng.common.HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

And my Main Component looks like this (removed unnecessary code):

```
var AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'app',
        templateUrl: 'app/app.view.html',
        directives: [
            ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
        ]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {}
    });

AppComponent = ng.router
    .RouteConfig([
        {path: '/search', name:"Search", component: SearchComponent},
        {path: '/results', name:"Results", component: ResultsComponent },
        {path: "*", component: SearchComponent }
    ])
    (AppComponent);
```

I am using:
angular: 2.0.0-rc.4
router: 3.0.0-beta.1

This is my scrip includes:

```
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/core.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/common.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/compiler.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/http.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-rc.4/router.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, did you figure it out? I have the same problem and I have been trying stuff for hours now...

Comment: @MaximeLaval No. I still have this error and I didn't find a way to fix it. If you find a solution please post as answer because I still want to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is `RouterConfig` instead of `RouteConfig` .

Code Sample from Angular tutorial [Link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html)

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
];
```

**Update**

```
.Class({
    constructor: [ ng.router.Router, function(router) {
            router.config([
                { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true },
                { path: '/heroes-list', name: 'Heroes', component: HeroesComponent },                
                { path: '/detail/:id', name: 'HeroDetail', component: HeroDetailComponent }
            ]);

    }]
});
```

Comment: If I try with `RouterConfig` I am getting almost same error: `ng.router.RouterConfig is not a function`  On official cheat sheet it's `ng.router.RouteConfig`. Here: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

Comment: I have no idea about angular 2 with javascript
check this answer it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711236/angular-2-routing-in-plain-javascript-no-typescript

Comment: The question/answers on that question are old and are using version 1 of router, the one used in beta versions.